# Windows Media Player in a Windows Form

Tags: c#

I have a form that has a media player and a button. When the button is clicked a song is supposed to play. However when the executable of the program is run, I won't know where the song is located. Is there a way to get a path of a file without searching through a directory to find it?

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\LMFAO - Party Rock Anthem.mp3";
    }
```

All the project files including the song will be in a folder. If the folder moves to another's computer and they run the executable, the path to the song will not be the same and so I need a way to figure out the path of the song.

Comment: I'm sure there is "a way to get a path", but your question sn't descriptive enough to be able to give a clear answer.

Comment: you need to share a network path to your music folder and use that

Comment: The folder that contains the song and the executable would be on someone else's computer, If I can get the path of the folder when it is on their computer, I can play the song

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the folder of your executable you can use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` and `Path.GetDirectoryName()` :

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
   string mp3FilePath = Path.Combine(path, "LMFAO - Party Rock Anthem.mp3");
   axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = mp3FilePath;
}
```